# obtain the id of a record (onchange) odoo

Tags: odoo, self

I have this code onchange

```
@api.onchange('the_geom')
    def _onchange_cor(self):
        if self.the_geom != False:
            self.env.cr.execute('SELECT the_geom from geolocalizacion_plot')
            self.cor2=self.env.cr.fetchone()[0]
            self.cor=self.id
```

but self.id returns `<openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f904b586e10>`

how to get the id of self (the current record)

Comment: @Prakash your answers were erased??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code or your concept here, but in on_changes odoo creates a new object and replaces self with it. The origin object, what you are looking for can be found under self._origin if i recall correct.

Why do you want to save self.id to self.cor?

Comment: i only save it for examine that it is correct, i used from "where" condition to a update in SQL, "self._origin.id" is correct, Thanks